# How can I check if a global variable that defined in Node.js if it's not changing after seconds

Tags: node.js

I wrote an app in nodejs but having logic problem with variable.
I'm looking for help with this issue.

Well, i have a global integer variable named "global_something" 
I need a function that check if "global_something" not changing after 1000ms or 2000ms

How i can do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: why not are you comparing the initial declared value in that function?

Comment: @DeepKakkar well, i just forgot about it in Nodejs that different with python. Lol.My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 variable for that

```
var original_global = 'Test';
var copy_original_global; // save this field in database or json file for compare  

setInterval(()=>{
  if(!copy_original_global){
      copy_original_global = original_global;
       return
 } 
 if(original_global != copy_original_global){
  console.log('Changed')
 }
}, 3000);
```